# Groups where every two generator subgroup is free

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there a name for the class of groups in the title, and any sort of characterization? Free groups and surface groups are in the class, but presumably there are many more...

Comment: If you have a closed hyperbolic 3-manifold $M$ with $dim H_1(M;F)\geq 3$ for a field $F$, then $\pi_1(M)$ has this property. 

Comment: I believe that this holds for any fully residually free group.  I think G. Baumslag proved it.

Comment: Non abelian of course!

Comment: @Agol: so presumably this holds for a subgroup of finite index in any closed hyp. manifold?

Comment: @Ben: Something is wrong. For fully residually free groups containing $\mathbb{Z}^2$ it is not true because $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is not free and 2-generated. Those that do not contain $\mathbb{Z}^2$ are hyperbolic, and are not that different from the surface group. For them the fact is obvious. Take $x,y$. If they commute, they generate a free (cyclic group). If they don't commute, consider a homomorphism into a free group separating $[x,y]$ from 1. In that case the images of $x,y$ do not commute, hence generate a free subgroup; thus $x,y$ generate a free subgroup too.  What did Baumslag prove?

Comment: Igor, regarding your comment: Not quite.  There are closed hyperbolic three-manifolds (eg certain Dehn fillings on certain knots) whose fundamental groups are two-generator, but (naturally) are not free. 

Comment: @Sam: Doesn't the usual "virtually" non-trivial $b_1$ conjecture also imply virtually arbitrarily large $b_1?$ Combinig Ian's comment with his announcement of the proof of the virtual everything conjectures would presumably imply what I say. Or am I confused?


Comment: @Igor: Perhaps you forgot "3-" in your comment. The property does not hold for higher dimensional hyperbolic manifolds.

Comment: @Mark: yes, of course, I was talking about 3-manifolds (I was responding to Ian, who was talking about such). Still, is the property known not to hold? I thought that it was at least conjectured that every hyp. manifold (of any dimension) has a cover with arbitrary high $b_1$...

Comment: Dear Igor - Suppose that $M$ is a closed hyperbolic three-manifold, say obtained as a Dehn filling of knot $K \subset S^3$, chosen so that $\Gamma = \pi_1(M)$ is a two-generator group.  Then $\Gamma$ is a finite index subgroup of itself (index one!) and is two-generator, but is not free.  So $\Gamma$ does not have the property you desire. Now, Ian recently proved the virtually infinite Betti number conjecture.  So $\Gamma$ has _some_ finite index subgroup with the property you desire. 

Comment: @Sam: right, that (the last two sentences) was exactly what I was saying. I believe that the virtual infinite $b_1$ conjecture is at least stated in all dimensions (proved in some special cases by Millson). On the other hand Ian's original comment is only made for kleinian groups (maybe that's what @Mark meant), but I have no intuition for whether it actually holds in higher dimensions...

Comment: @Mark, it was B Baumslag who proved that any 2 elements of a residually free group that do not commute generate a free subgroup. The proof is trivial. Map to a free group separating the commutator of the elements from 1. Then the images of the two elements generate a free group and hence the original 2 elements generate a free group. 

Comment: Oh I see you wrote the proof down. I didn't claim it was deep. It was the paper introducing fully residually free. 

Comment: If you need a name, how about '2-locally free'?

Comment: @ Igor: I mistated the result. If $F=\mathbb{Q}$, then it's ok. If $F=\mathbb{F}_q$ a finite field, then one needs $dim H_1(M;\mathbb{F}_q)\geq 4$. This follows from results of Shalen-Wagreich. Lubotzky proved that any hyperbolic 3-manifold has a finite-sheeted cover with $rank H_1 \geq k$ for any $k$, essentially by strong-approximation.   

Comment: Igor - Apparently Culler and Shalen call this property "2-free" - there are quite a few papers relating $k$-freeness and volume of hyperbolic three-manifolds. Eg google the phrase "k-free shalen" without quotes.  Cheers!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no name, there are lots of examples. Guba gave many non-trivial examples in Guba, V. S. Conditions under which 2-generated subgroups in small cancellation groups are free.
Izv. Vyssh. Uchebn. Zaved. Mat. 1986, no. 7, 12–19 and here: Guba, V. S.
A finitely generated simple group with free 2-generated subgroups. 
Sibirsk. Mat. Zh. 27 (1986), no. 5, 50–67. There are of course infinitely generated locally free non-free groups. Every proper ascending HNN extension of a free group is an extension of such a group by a cyclic group. See also Arzhantseva, G. N. Olʹshanskiĭ, A. Yu.
Generality of the class of groups in which subgroups with a lesser number of generators are free. Mat. Zametki 59 (1996), no. 4, 489--496, 638; translation in 
Math. Notes 59 (1996), no. 3-4, 350–355.

Comment: This is really great phrase "there is no name, there are lots of examples" :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is a widely used term *binary finite* (*бинарно конечная*, in Russian) group, see papers of Shunkov, Chernikov and their school. This means a group where all 2-generated subgruops are finite.

For instance, the [*Kourovka Notebook*](http://math.nsc.ru/~alglog/17kt.pdf) contains the following question (still open, as far as I know).

**Question 4.74(b)** (V.P.Shunkov, 1973). Does there exist a simple infinite binary finite 2-group?

Also, I stumbled across *binary solvable* and *binary nilpotent* groups... As you can guess, I am hinting that
you may call your groups 
**binary free**
if you like this terminology.